# How to reverse GridLayout construction with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using RecyclerView to display a grid of items. I would like to reverse the construction of this layout.

***setStackFromEnd()*** works perfectly with a **LinearLayoutManager** but it's not supported with the **GridLayoutManager**, as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean)).

What is the best alternative to build a reversed grid with RecyclerView ?

Answer (score 6):

Have you try to set the reverse layout into the GridLayoutManager constructor, for example :

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 6, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, true));
```

The boolean is for reverse layout.

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I tried, but I still have this problem of scrolling to bottom of RecyclerView when displayed ...

Comment: mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0); should do the trick but for now, i don't know why it scroll by itself to the bottom

Answer (score 3):

**You Can Reverse Any Layout Manager**

**Step1-** goto your **ArrayList**

**Step2-** Reverse `Collections.reverse(mArrayList);`

**Step2-** Set Adapter

Answer (score 0):

You should do exactly what Android Docs you linked suggest:

> `stackFromEnd` is not supported by `GridLayoutManager`. Consider using `setReverseLayout(boolean)`.

Modify your code to work with `setReverseLayout`.

Comment: I tried this method but the problem is that when the RecyclerView is displayed, the screen is automatically scrolled to the bottom. Well I want it to be scrolled to the top.

Comment: do you have paging in your `RecyclerView`? or is it like a fixed data setup?

Comment: My RecyclerView uses paging

Comment: So your paging is at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say we have a ordered number of list on RecyclerView and it looks like this:
1
2
3
4
5

When we use “setReverseLayout(true)”, it will turn out to this:
5
4
3
2
1

However, when we want to add a new item on this recyclerview dynamically, it will add the item as a last item and it will stack from the end.
5
4
3
2
1
6
Therefore, “setStackFromEnd(true)” comes out here. It says the recyclerview; stack the new items to the beginning. Let’s look at the recyclerview: 
6
5
4
3
2
1
setStackFromEnd wont work for the gridlayout that's why the scroll is at the end of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

When i encountered this same issue,i tried using `RecyclerView.reverseLayout()` but it always left a blank space at the top when the items aren't uniform.

The solution that work for me is using arraylist `reverse` method in kotlin similar to `Collection.reverse(arraylist)` in java.

So just call `dataList.reverse()` on your dataset before passing it to the adapter.

Note: If you're using the adapter position to load the item from another activity,you would have to reverse the dataset there too.

For example, you're loading a DetailsActivity when the RecyclerView item is clicked,make sure you reverse the dataset in the DetailsActivity too before getting the clicked item or else you'd get the wrong item.